# How do I get metadata from Spotify SDK on Android?

Tags: android, metadata, spotify, spotify-app

I'm building an app with the lastest [Spotify SDK](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/releases), it's working fine but now i want to get **LoginUser's metadata** as displayName, birthday and country, also want to get **Track's metadata** as Artist, SongName, Album, YearFromAlbum(if its possible), I can only get track's URI, duration, playing?, shuffle?, repeat?

I also followed this [tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/tutorial/) and read a lot from:
[developer.spotify.com/android-sdk-docs/index.html?com/spotify/sdk/android/](http://developer.spotify.com/android-sdk-docs/index.html?com/spotify/sdk/android/) 
but nothing.

Thanks for your help and time.
Regards.

PS: I'm Loggin in through WebView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Spotify SDK](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk) does not currently have functions for metadata lookup or playlist management, for that you need to use [Spotify Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/)

You can call directly the API or use a wrapper like this [Spotify Web API for Android](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android)

Comment: Thank you ! I followed those 2 tutorials and I get what I wanted. Thanks Kaaes for the wrapper =)

Answer (score 2):

> To get Track's metadata as Artist, SongName, Album, YearFromAlbum

you will want to use the web-api documented here : https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/endpoint-reference/

> i want to get LoginUser's metadata as displayName, birthday and country

the '/v1/me' endpoint should cover this as much as currently possible
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-current-users-profile/

Since Spotify doesnt have a java library you can use directly for web apis,  you will want to make your own or pick one of the java/android libraries listed here :

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/#libraries